# How to set the gravity of image view in a listview programatically?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, alignment

I have arranged textview to the left side of the listview programatically?But in the case of image view it is not happening.Why?The code for the imageview is given below.How to set it to the left side of the listview.I tried

```
tr.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

this one but still imageview is in the centre[image]

```
tr = new TableRow(AAAView.this);

                    tr.setWeightSum(2);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(param3);
                    tr.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);                        
                    final ImageView b16513 = new ImageView(AAAView.this);

                    b16513.setLayoutParams(param1);
                    b16513.setTag(getAAADetails.datalist.get(i).Assist_Comp_Mobile);
                    b16513.setImageResource(R.drawable.callbutton);

                    b16513.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                                    Uri.parse("tel:"
                                            + b16513.getTag().toString()));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });




param1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
    param2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
    param3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    param1.setMargins(1, 0, 1, 1);
    param2.setMargins(10, 0, 5, 1);
```

Comment: Is your imageView layout  param wrap_content?

Answer (score 0):

If you use gravity, it is the text/image inside the button what is going to be placed on the left (inside its view).
layout_gravity moves the view inside its container. Try using it.

I'm sorry if I'm mistaken here, but try with it.